# Notification API - notification opens new web page when clicked without click event listener

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, notifications

**Background**: I am developing an MVC core 2.0 web application. I am currently working on adding a feature to the application that uses the [Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification). For testing purposes, I have made a JavaScript function that runs when I reach the app's home page. The code immediately creates a new Notification and displays it.

**The Problem**: Currently, when I click on the notification, instead of simply closing, the notification closes and opens a new tab in my browser, sending me to the landing page for my web app. How can I configure the notification to simply close when clicked? This problem appears to only happen in Google Chrome; it does not happen in Edge.

**Things I've Tried**: I've read the documentation linked above several times and tried copying their code and examples. From what I can tell I've done nothing different but the results don't change for me. So far no StackOverflow questions I've seen cover this issue.

**My Code**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var ask = Notification.requestPermission();

    ask.then(function (permission) {

        switch (permission) {
            case "granted":

                var message = new Notification("notification title",
                {
                    body: "notification body",
                    badge: "imageurl"
                });

                break;

            case "default":
            case "denied":
                break;
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Try inspecting that element and using the Chrome Dev Tools' "Event Listeners" tab. Un-check "Ancestors" near the top and it should display all events bound to that element. If you don't find what you're looking for, work up the DOM tree. Best.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I will look into that.

Comment: From what I've found the notification created by the Notification API is a system-level event; I'm unable to inspect the notification with browser Dev Tools because it's not a browser element or a part of the DOM.
Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you've found?